# "Error: could not find a valid GNU Make executable" with Cygwin and NDK

Tags: android, gnu, android-ndk, gnu-make

I'm new to the NDK. (using Windows). I have downloaded cygwin and the NDK. I have unzipped the NDK in `C:\`. When I run cygwin I change to the NDK directory and I run the command

```
build/host-setup.sh
```

But I get:

```
Error: could not find a valid GNU Make executable.
```

I have downloaded GNU make 3.81 but still no luck.

What do I have to do with GNU Make? Do I have to put it in a special
directory or add it to PATH?

Comment: Have you tried to run `make` from the shell?

Comment: Yep, i get cant open perl script "C:\Program": No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this, GNU make is not selected by default in the cygwin installer so when installing cygwin you have to select GNU Make as part of the install

Answer (score 0):

Is your NDK installed under c:\Program Files, if so maybe try moving it to a new path location that doesn't have any spaces in the path name