# Error in Android NDK make program cannot find

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

I am trying to set up Android NDK using this [Link](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/).

I started Set up process by following command **make -v** and i am getting

```
    $ make -v      
    bash: make: command not found
```

Then I entered following commands as given in the above link

```
cd /cygwin/C/..path for my project

/cygwin/C/..path of ndk installed path
```

At this point I am getting

```
ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.
```

Note, I checked all this possibility error links:

[Link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695707/ndk-android-mk-gnu-make)

[Link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410749/android-ndk-gnu-make-problems)

Removed Spaces between folder.

Check this:

[image: Screenshot image]

Comment: @Alex How can i set path for android sdk and cygwin in batch.profile file?

Comment: I've never done that. I usually type something like /cygdrive/c/android-ndk/ndk-build from my project's jni dir. I guess you can set some aliases to that effect as they in linux do.

Comment: @Venky, I'm not sure, that I understood you right. Basically, your global PATH variables are both valid for cygwin environment and for Windows. It is also possible to supply them with "/" sign, which needed for cygwin.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.`

While trying to install Cygwin i missed out to install **MAKE PACKAGE**

Just need to search **make** in the **Search box** and it will shows the Branches that includes devel branch and from devel branch i selected make package.

That's all issue fixed.

Check this [Youtube link for Complete Set up process for Android NDK.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMV7Xqcn39k)

Explained from SDK set up process to NDK Set up process.

Comment: the video isn't available anymore

Answer (score 4):

You're probably missing the devel branch in cygwin.  Open the installer and on the package selection screen find "Devel".  Next to it, it reads "default".  click this to install the entire branch and you should be good after install.

Comment: How can i set path for android sdk and cygwin in batch.profile file?

Comment: You should have a `~/.bashrc` file.  You can add `export PATH=$PATH:C:\path\to\NDK` to the end of that file.

Then you need to execute `source ~/.bashrc` to make the updates take

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be

- to install (in addition) [GnuMake for Win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm) - it has an appropriate version >3.81
- to create environment variable `GNUMAKE` and point it to `your_path/GnuMake32/bin`
- to call via cygwin `make -v` and enjoy the result

Hopefully helps.

*But baseline is simple - it is really better to deploy something like Ubuntu (as separate OS or via VM) and run NDK there.*

Comment: How can i set path for android sdk and cygwin in batch.profile file?

Comment: My suggestion is to start from [here](http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html#environ).

Answer (score 1):

Probably Cygwin developer package is not installed. By default it is not installed. You, probably, should run Cygwin installer and install developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add cygwin/bin(like C:\cygwin64\bin) path to System Environment Variables.