# What else do I need to do before the NDK is set up?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have been working on setting up the NDK from this website for a few days now, but still can't get it to work correctly: http://psrdotcom.blogspot.fr/2011/12/android-ndk-jni-windows-xp7-with-3264.html.

I am stuck at using the 'javah' command but think that it must have to do with my PATH variables. I have set the JAVA_HOME and NDK_HOME as well as PATH, but I must have set them incorrectly. Could someone help clarify what they mean by the JAVA_HOME and NDK_HOME directory? I know it means the java and ndk directory, but i've read some places that it needs to be the bin folder, or something like that. Here is a picture of when I try to run the javah command:

EDIT:
since I have less than ten reputation, I have to link the picture... but here is the link
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FYd6.png

Comment: [Spend some time to watch this Video for NDK installation in Windows](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMV7Xqcn39k).. Also Check my [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213626/error-in-android-ndk-make-program-cannot-find)

Comment: Thanks, I'm watching that video now.

Comment: @Venky if you could possibly answer this question...The project I am doing already has all of the C code written, I just need to access it in an Android application. Since the javah command that I can't get to work is just creating a header file for the practice code I am writing, can I skip that step? All the header files are already written.

Comment: @user1490917 I don't have too much idea on it , but it seems you have to use [Blue Cove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/source/checkout) and Maven to compile your App.. This is the clue i can give

Comment: @Venky Also, is there anywhere I can find the debugging guide your intern Chris had made? Looks like the most detailed instruction set I've seen online yet.

Comment: Sorry, I had made the assumption that you were the one who made that YouTube tutorial that you had posted. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

No matter what version of JDK you are using,Just use

```
javah -classpath ..\bin\classes com.samplendk.SampleNDKActivity
```

Comment: Hey, this is user1490917, that was on my home computer. I have version 1.7.

Comment: @JuiCe I had test on jdk 1.7 now. please also use                   javah -classpath ..\bin\classes com.samplendk.SampleNDKActivity